# Binding extjs combobox to a inner object

Tags: extjs, extjs4

my combobox will always have only one record store assigned to it, that comes from the server like this way:

```
[
{
    "consulta_id": 23752, 
    "convenio_id": 1, 
    "data": "2012-07-11", 
    "id": 36569, 
    "paciente": {
        "nome": "Alvasole", 
        "id": 12
     }, 
    "tipo": 1
}, 
{
    "consulta_id": 23753, 
    "convenio_id": 61, 
    "data": "2012-07-11", 
    "id": 36579,
    "paciente": {
        "nome": "Felintoi", 
        "id": 33
     }, 
    "tipo": 1
}
]
```

In this case, the store needs to be assigned to 'paciente' object (with id and nome).
I'm not getting this automatically to work.

This way works, but needs to be called manually:

```
setData: function(data) {
    this.getStore().loadRawData(data.get('paciente'));
    this.select(this.getStore().getAt(0));
},
```

Comment: How to load this inner object automatically to ComboBox store.

Answer (score 0):

One way to flatten out your Model is to use `mapping` attribute and use dot notation to get to the nested object's fields like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Paciente', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[
       {name:'id', mapping:'paciente.id'}
       ...
     ]
});
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by that?